# How to check whether request is finished in Python Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I have two classes in my Tornado application.

First class is `BaseRequestHandler`, which extends `tornado.web.RequestHandler` and overrides `prepare()` method of it for API Key validation of all incoming requests.

Second one is route specific class `ChildRequestHandler`, which extends `BaseRequestHandler`.

`ChildRequestHandler` also has `prepare()` method which does some parameter validation but before that it calls `prepare()` method of `BaseRequestHandler`.

Now, `prepare()` method of both classes calls `finish()` methods of `tornado.web.RequestHandler` if validation fails.

Following are the examples of both the classes.

**Base Class**

```
class BaseRequestHandler(RequestHandler):
    # Override Write Error method
    def write_error(self, status_code, chunk):
        self.set_status(status_code)
        self.finish({'message': chunk})

    # Prepare method to validate API Key
    def prepare(self):
        # Send Unauthorized error
        if 'X-API-KEY' not in self.request.headers:
            self.write_error(401, 'API Key {X-API-KEY} Required')
            return None

        # Set API Key from header
        self.apikey = self.request.headers['X-API-KEY']
```

**Child class**

```
class ChildRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):

    # Check for required parameters
    def prepare(self):
        # Call Prepare of base class
        super(ChildRequestHandler, self).prepare()

        username = self.get_query_argument('username', None)
        if username is None:
            self.write_error(400, 'Username {username} Required')
```

The problem occurs when validation fails in Base class. Then it throws Runtime error `finish() called twice` as `prepare()` method of child class is also executed regardless of validation result of Base class.

This can be solved by returning boolean from `prepare()` method of Base class to identify whether the validation passed or not and then accordingly allow execution of `prepare()` method of child class.

But is there anything like `self.finished()` to identify whether the request is already finished? I checked the documentation and could not find any such method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a public `finished()` method (although there's no reason why one couldn't be added). I recommend raising a subclass of `tornado.web.HTTPError` instead of calling `write_error` directly, so that `prepare()` won't return normally after producing the error.

Comment: Oh yes... How could I miss this !! Thank you.
Now I am raising the `HTTPError` and also overridden the `write_error` method to send the `application/json` response.